# iPad - iPhone Large UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, ipad, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to make a large spinner (with grey style, about 80x80px) but it looks low quality.
Is there a way to make it high quality or to replace the animated image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done using UIActivityIndicatorView. you can however write your own subclass of UIView using an UIImageView and some simple animation to do this for you.

Answer (score 62):

Actually, you can set the indicator style of your `UIActivityIndicatorView` to Large White, and then in code do this:

```
// Objective-C
[myActivityView setColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
// Swift 4.0
myActivityView.color = .grayColor
```

Comment: hmm tried this, but it didnt work for me: reason: '-[UIActivityIndicatorView setColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6287d0'

Comment: Add this test: if ([myActivityView  respondsToSelector:@selector(setColor:)]) {
}

Comment: This is the best answer. Works easy.

Comment: excellent! Can confirm works in Swift on iOS 8: myActivityView.color = UIColor.redColor()

Answer (score 9):

Swift 2.0 Solution

```
myActivityView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
myActivityView.color = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    func makeLargeGray() {
        activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
        color = .gray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
```

However, if you make it big enough, you'll be able to see the pixels...

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    func makeLargeGray() {
        style = .whiteLarge
        color = .gray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A useful project that you can start off with is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).